# IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-tools

new to ibm bluemix. Steps to be followed to develop a application on eclipse and to depoy using IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix and cloud foundry as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could find all information you may need for your question in the Bluemix Documentation
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/

On the following URL you could find a "Step by step" guide using Bluemix tool:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html

Instead on the following URL you could find a "Step by step" guide using CF push for a Java app on liberty runtime: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

Comment: Hi,can you be specific about the method on how I can push application to bluemix.Which method is simpler? is it using eclipse plugin or CF push.Wil I be able to run the application on eclipse using localHost?How can I test my application in eclipse?

Comment: There is not a 'simpler' method. I prefer CF push because I like to have much control. But if you have to develop a Java web application, maybe, the bluemix tool could be useful because you can push the entire server.xml directly from eclipse. You can test your application as described in documentation (if you are developing liberty profile app you should download and configure WebSphere local server).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can follow the instructions here for installing the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix

Secondly, you can follow this tutorial to know how to push an application to Bluemix using the tooling. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/941f1004-4e3d-4a4b-87ed-30d8045fde4e/resource/IBM%20Bluemix%20Tutorial%20-%20Connecting%20Eclipse%20to%20Bluemix%20v2.0_files/IBMBluemixTutorial-ConnectingEclipsetoBluemixv2.0.pdf?lang=en

There might be some UI differences in the IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix tools that you will install from the first link vs what is shown in the second link. These differences are however just cosmetic (like using terms IBM bluemix vs Cloud foundry while defining a server). Overall the functionality remains the same.

Also apart from the use-case described in the tutorial (second link), you can also create new projects (web projects) in eclipse and push them to Bluemix.

In order to test your projects locally, you would need to install local WAS liberty profile (in case of JavaEE projects) or local node js (in case of nodejs apps). You can do all the testing locally on the local servers and once you're confident about your development, you can push the projects to Bluemix.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a very old thread but this will be helpful for future references. One can setup the Bluemix server in an IDE like eclipse by straight forward adding a new server and can push the application directly. However a more user friendly approach is to deploy it from cf commandline. You can deploy the application independently or even package it with the local server. You even have the options to provide inputs like hostname in the commandline. Please go through the Bluemix docs for detailed specifications.