# How to debug spring boot application remotely on Bluemix with eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, debugging, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I have deployed a spring boot application on bluemix and trying to link the app in eclipse but could not link it. 
I have deployed sprint boot out of the tool and trying to manage (debug) from with in the eclipse with bluemix tools.

Comment: You need some basic set up done.
This should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864707/ibm-eclipse-tools-for-bluemix

Comment: Hi Rakshith, thanks for pointing me to the documentation. I was successful to deploy a war file but i was trying to do a spring boot app to deploy to bluemix from eclipse. As per the documentation i was trying to link my application in eclipse but its not happening.

Comment: What is the error you are hitting with?

Comment: @RiyaMRoy , 1. How bluemixtools understand the spring boot application in workspace can be deployed to bluemix(what setting are needed to the sprint boot application like fecets or the project type etc. ..  2. could not upload an image but the error is "Unable to create module for <Project>. Failed to link the project with <project>"

Comment: Just to add one more point, I am using java build pack not the liberty build pack